# Уголок на CSS3

Tags: css3, css

Есть задача: к некоторым `div` на странице приделать уголок. Примеры :

- Уголок у div, который лежит внутри другого блока

[image]

- Уголок у отдельного balloon.

[image]

Стоить заметить, что на уголки распространяется прозрачность и градиент. Как такое сделать на css3, я пытался сделать тоже самое с помощью `:before` и `:after`, но для создания такого уголка нужно было манипулировать границами, а в этом случае начинаются проблемы с градиентами и прозрачностью. Ваши предложения.

P.S ещё есть вариант сделать это с помощью SVG, но CSS3 лучше

Comment: могу лишь дать полезные линки ;)
http://htmlbook.ru/blog/kak-sdelat-slovesnyi-puzyr-na-css3-bez-kartinok
http://htmlbook.ru/blog/kak-sdelat-zagnutye-ugolki-na-css3-bez-kartinok
http://htmlbook.ru/blog/kak-sdelat-lenty-na-css3-bez-kartinok

Comment: Не думали подключить к этому canvas?

Comment: @ling канва для мелких штуковин?! Я ещё не видел популярного сайта (да,да, сайты васи пупкина не в счёт), который юзает канву по мелкотне

Answer (score 1):

Я делал такой уголок через обычный CSS2. Просто создается треугольник. Техника описана [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/) к примеру.
Но наверное лучше применить там transform: rotate; То есть создать прямоугольник и повернуть его под углом. 
Еще можно вот [так](http://jsfiddle.net/DrLdx/).

Comment: Проблема не в самом уголке, уголок я делал по той же технике, что описана на хабре, проблема в прозрачности http://jsfiddle.net/DrLdx/367/ вот пример. у уголка небольшая проблема с прозрачностью + на макетах у уголка есть граница, которая делается вторым уголком подложенным под низ, но уголка делается с помощью border и в данном случае получается сложность с отображением не прозрачной "границы" и прозрачного "содержимого" у уголка лежащего под другим уголком. вот в этом проблема.

Comment: А зачем вы используете after? Разве нельзя просто вложить треугольник в блок?

Answer (score 1):

Резать бгшками, без ксс3, можно сделать какой угодно хинт, фикс ширин или динамический.

Что то вроде этого но с уголком [ПНГ блок по ширине контента](http://webhint.info/2011/11/png-blok-po-shyryne-kontenta-bez-javascript/)